# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2000 Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to connect to MS SQL databases and I can connect normally without any issues using the following code:

```
 const sequelize = new Sequelize(
      database,
      user,
      password,
      {
        host: host,
        dialect: "mssql",
        port: port,
        dialectOptions: {
          options: {
            encrypt: false,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.send("Connected");
      })
```

This works very well for any new database (example: Version 14)
However, when I try to connect to a SQL database whose version is 8.00.2055 I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown type: 0
    at Function.parseTokens (C:\snapshot\Backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:145:17)
    at parseTokens.next (<anonymus>)
    at next (internal/streams/from.js:31:46)
    at next (internal/streams/from.js:35:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I found a fix on [Tedious github](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/62) that should solve this by specifying the Tedious version to 7.1:

```
    options: {
    tdsVersion: '7_1'
}
```

But this fix did not work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mainstream support for SQL Server 2000 ended in 2005, extended support in 2013. There will never be any patches or security fixes made available for such software, you really should encourage those responsible to migrate the databases on that server to newer supported versions and decommission that one.

Comment: I really tried. I have been arguing with them about the need to upgrade for the past 3 weeks. They wouldn't budge and now I am trying to find the solution. If I can't find one by the end of the month I will just tell them unsupported and there is nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("MET", "met", "met", {
  host: "10.7.12.1",
  dialect: "mssql",
  port: 1433,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      packetSize: 16368,
      tdsVersion: "7_1",
      trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
  },
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Also these are my dependencies on package.json file, note the sequelize and tedious versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.19.0",
    "tedious": "^15.0.0"
  },
```

My entity usuarios file:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = require("../util/database");

const usuario = sequelize.define(
  "usuario",
  {
    usuario: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },   
    pass: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    rol: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false, createdAt: false, updatedAt: false }
);

module.exports = usuario;
```

My app.js file

```
const usuario = require("./models/usuario");
usuario
   .findAll()
   .then((res) => console.log(res))
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

This is working for me using SQL Server 2000.
Hopes it helps you
Best regards.

Comment: I did the same but got this error [Error Image](https://ibb.co/nBPcF8j)

Comment: Are you sure you are using tedious version 15.0.0 and sequelize 6.19.0?. I had look in my /node_modules/tedious/lib/connectio  file and I couldn't  find the line that is getting you that error.  So my guess it has to be some package version problem. I'm connected to a SQL server 2000 using the code in my answer. You should try a simple entity.findAll() request instead of sequelize.authenticate.

Comment: I am using the following:     
"sequelize": "^6.17.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1",
"tedious": "^15.0.1"
I will try the entity.findAll() and reply with what it returns

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: I have update my answer with my entity file and my app.js file. I suggest you to create an empty project only for tests purposes with that dependencies run npm install and create a simple entity like mine and test again. Best of luck